# Некорректное чтение данных из файла

Tags: c++, fstream

Ввожу и считываю данные этим кодом

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int n;
    char f[8];
};

struct List{
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    int count;
};

void addNode(List *L){
    Node *temp;
    temp = new Node;
    cout << endl << "Введите число: ";
    cin >> temp->n;
    cout << endl << "Введите f: ";
    char Lol[8];
    cin >> Lol;
    strcpy_s(temp->f, Lol);
    if(L->head != NULL){
        L->tail = L->head;
        L->head = temp;
    } else {
        L->head = temp;
    }
    L->count++;
}

void insertNode(List * L, Node * N){
    if(L->head != NULL){
        L->tail = L->head;
        L->head = N;
    } else {
        L->head = N;
    }
    L->count++;
}

void createList(List *L){
    L->count = 0;
    L->head=L->tail=NULL;
}

int main(){
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    string path = "file.txt";

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(path);
    if(!fin.is_open()){
        cout << endl << "Ввод данных: " << endl;
        List L;
        createList(&L);
        addNode(&L);
        addNode(&L);
        ofstream fout;
        fout.open(path, ios::app);
        if(!fout.is_open()) cout << "GLOBAL ERROR!" << endl;
        else {
            cout << "Новые данные успешно сохранены!" << endl;
            fout.write((char*)&L, sizeof(List));
            cout << endl << L.count << endl;
            for(int i = 0; i < L.count; i++){
                Node * N = new Node;
                fout.write((char*)N, sizeof(Node));
            }
        }
        fout.close();
    } else {
        cout << "Файл открыт!" << endl;
        List Ls;
        fin.read((char*)&Ls, sizeof(List));
        int count = Ls.count;
        createList(&Ls);
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            Node * Nd = new Node;
            fin.read((char*)Nd, sizeof(Node));
            cout << Nd->n << "\t" << Nd->f << endl;
            insertNode(&Ls, Nd);
        }
        cout << endl << "Успешно выгружено!" << endl;
        if(Ls.head != NULL) cout << endl << Ls.head->f << "\t" << Ls.tail->f << endl;
        else {
            cout << "NULL \tcount = " << count << endl;
        }
    }
    fin.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Здесь мы задаем 2 структуры Node, которые в последствие впихиваем в структуру List

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При чтении данных получается непонятно. Данные структуры List, т.е. count передается как надо, в отличие от данных структуры Node, они выглядят непонятно как

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо заполненных нод вы пытаетесь писать в файл куски неинициализированной памяти, что приводит к неопределенному поведениюЖ

```
Node * N = new Node;
fout.write((char*)N, sizeof(Node));
```

Еще перед этим вы пишите в файл структуру с указателями, которые протухают и не могут быть использованы после чтения из файла в другом процессе.

```
fout.write((char*)&L, sizeof(List));
```

И память утекает стремительным потоком...